# understanding drag and drop in HTML

Tags: html, filelist, dto

I'm having difficulties understanding the drag and drop in HTML 5, particularly the dropeffect and effectsallowed properties. I've looked through documentations and examples but I still don't get a good grip. Particularly, the fact that you can drag data inside a page and on the other hand files from outside the page obscures things for me.

First, when I drag an image that's inside a page to a drop area the FileList of the DataTransfer object is empty. But does that mean you also can't access images in a page the same way as with files from outside the page? (e.g. get their properties or feed them to a FileReader)

The other thing I don't understand is dropEffect and effectsAllowed. Do they work in combination with the setData and getData methods or with files dragged from outside the page?

I would think that if I set **event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = ' move'**,  then a file outside the page would actually be moved and be gone in the old location. However, I don't see any actual difference between move/link/copy, when I drag something into the page, apart from the dropEffect string value.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm no answers yet, but I got a little further. Just in case anyone else is wondering about this:

The **dropEffect** and **effectsAllowed** properties are apparently just visual cues for the drag operation. Nothing more, nothing less. That means the cursor icon changes according to the used effect. Here is a small script where you can see it in action: http://help.dottoro.com/ljffjemc.php

The thing is that Firefox (15) uses the standard drop cursor when you set **effectsAllowed** to more than one effect (e.g. copymove). This behaviour is at the moment of writing different in Chrome, which just uses the icon specified with **dropEffect**. The latter seems more logical to me, so perhaps Firefox is just buggy about it.

I found out that this visual cues work with both elements inside a web page as well as files from outside the browser.

But setting the **dropEffect** to for example 'move' has nothing to do with really moving the file.